# Generic Types Return in Typescript

Tags: generics, typescript

I have a Interface find which consists of method cal();
Class a1 and a2 implements the interface. a1 returns a number while a2 returns string. How can i define a single interface to solve my issue.

The below is having the snippet of what is mentioned.

```
interface Ifind {
    cal() : string;
}

class a1 implements Ifind{

    public cal():string{
        return "10";
    }
}

class a2 implements Ifind{
    public cal(): number{
        return 12;
    }
}

class main{
    private obj;

    constructor() {
        this.obj = new a1();
        var p = this.obj.cal();
        alert(p)
    }
}
```

[in TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Ifind%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cal()%20%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20a1%20implements%20Ifind%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20cal()%3Astring%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%2210%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20a2%20implements%20Ifind%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20cal()%3A%20number%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%2012%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20main%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20obj%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.obj%20%3D%20new%20a1()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20p%20%3D%20this.obj.cal()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(p)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Change the return type of cal() to `string | number`. But I'd rather think about why som IFind return a number and others return a string. Couldn't they all return the same type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the interface generic.

```
// Edited for naming   
interface Find<T> {
    cal() : T;
}

class A1 implements Find<string> {
    cal(): string {
        return "10";
    }
}

class A2 implements Find<number> {
    cal(): number {
        return 12;
    }
}
```

A few comments on the code above.

TypeScript, as a superset of JavaScript, has first class functions which makes the code above pretty ugly and unidiomatic.

It would be much better to simply write a function.

```
function a1() {
  return "10";
}

function a2() {
  return 12;
}
```

Of course your actual code may be more complex, but if you have an interface with only one member, and if that member is a function, just use a function.

I also edited the code for style. Specifically, both type and class names should be **PascalCased**.

Comment: Nice answer. Just one question. Why shouldn't the interface not be prefixed with I? Do you have a refenrece backing that up?

Comment: Actually, this used to be recommended by the https://typescriptlang.org documentation but it seems to have been removed. It is the [style followed by the TypeScript team for _internal_ use](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines#names) but that is not meant to be prescriptive for consumers of the language. I would say it is not necessarily a bad practice, just not very common. I would adapt my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Interessting why they decided that. After all they also do have C# where prefixing interfaces with I is good practice.