# How can I extend an interface and override a property's type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a pretty complicated object with multiple properties that I'd like to extend and override a specific property.

```
interface ComplicatedObject {
  propertyOne: string,
  propertyTwo: null
}

interface MoreComplicatedObject extends ComplicatedObject {
  propertyTwo: string
}
```

Essentially, objects with the type `ComplicatedObject` are converted to the `MoreComplicatedType` by assigning a string value to `propertyTwo`. I'd like to avoid using a union type on `propertyTwo` because all calls using `propertyTwo` assume that it's a string, not a null value, so I'd rather not have to include type checks in every instance where I access `propertyTwo`.

How can I extend an interface and override the type of an existing property?

Comment: Doing this would violate the Liskov Substitution Principal.  Can you make `ComplicatedObject` a generic interface, and make `propertyTwo` of the generic type?  This way you wouldn't need `MoreComplicatedObject` at all, and aren't violating LSP.  TypeScript 2.3 supports default type parameters, so you wouldn't have to always supply the parameter.

Comment: Another thing you could do is use a `Pick` type to pick out the properties you want to keep as-is, then add new properties with whatever types you want. Like `interface MoreComplicatedObject extends Pick<ComplicatedObject, "propertyOne"> { propertyTwo: string; }`

Comment: For those who want to override `propertyOne` to make it accept `null` (or `undefined` by replacing null keyword) :

`interface ComplicatedObject {
  propertyOne: string,
  propertyTwo: null | string
}`

`interface MoreComplicatedObject extends Omit<ComplicatedObject, 'propertyOne'> {
  propertyOne: string | null
}`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can override property type when extending an interface only if the type in the extending interface is compatible with original type of the property. Usual case is when you are overriding it with more restrictive type.

It means that you have to have foresight and declare original property with a type that will be compatible with all possible extensions. In your case, you can use union type in `ComplicatedObject`:

```
interface ComplicatedObject {
  propertyOne: string,
  propertyTwo: null | string
}

interface MoreComplicatedObject extends ComplicatedObject {
  propertyTwo: string
}
```

Or you can make `CompicatedObject` generic as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44062654/43848).

Comment: This answer is correct for the OP since it overrides from 'null | string' type to 'string' type.
But It will not work for people like me wanting to move from 'string' type to 'string | null' type, because type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string', because 'null' is not assignable to 'string'.

Comment: @HamzaDahmoun I've posted another answer that will allow you to override without having to pre-plan your parent type.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `Omit<T, K>`, which allows you to omit certain keys of a type. You can then use `&` to append the keys you want.

```
type A = {a: string, b: string}
type B = Omit<A, 'b'> & {b: number}
```

Note that you can declare `A` as an interface, `Omit<T,K>` similarly works.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBDAXFAzsATgSwDsBzAGigCMNt9iBfAKFEigCEEoB5AWz2AB4YZAOTkhAPigAyZJSgEArl3IQcDAMYB7AtijpW7VBiEohZWQEYotIA)

Answer (score -1):

Using the `type-fest` npm package, you can use the `Merge` helper to overwrite/override any property on the original, however you like:

```
import {Merge} from 'type-fest'

type ComplicatedObject = {
  propertyOne: string,
  propertyTwo: null
}

type MoreComplicatedObject = Merge<ComplicatedObject, {
  propertyTwo: string
}>
```

This may work with interfaces too, but I've only used it with object types.